# uso de contadores en un WHILE

Tags: php

Cordial saludo.
Actualmente en mi sitio web, tengo un formulario para ingresar registros de llantas montadas y desmontadas a un vehículo. El vehículo tiene 11 llantas, lo que quiere decir que  en el formulario le pueden ingresar desde una llanta hasta 11 llantas. Como lo que deseo es ingresar los campos en el formulario que contengan información, estoy utilizando un WHILE anidado dentro de un FOR. Las campos del formulario que deseo insertar son los códigos de las llantas. Cada campo en el formulario esta asociado a una variable, las cuales nombre así: $IDM1...$IDM11. Con el FOR, busco validar si en los 11 campos del formulario hay información y con el WHILE busco contar, cuantos campos del formulario tienen información. Como el nombre de las variables solo difiere, en el numero al final que va desde 1 a 11, pensé en formar las variables dentro del WHILE concatenando así: "$IDM".$i.

Este es el código:

```
//contador llantas montadas
$iM=0;
for ($i=1; $i<=11; $i+1) { 
    while ("$IDM".$i!="") {
        $iM+1;
        break;
    }
}
```

una vez le doy ejecutar en la pagina web, se queda cargando mucho rato y sale este error.

Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /var/www/html/analistaflota/RegistroSalidaLlantas.php on line 389

Agradezco  toda la ayuda que puedan brindarme.

Comment: Por favor explica de mejor manera que tienes, que quieres, y que buscas lograr. Ahora mismo veo un for, que por lo que dices funciona mal. Pero no sabemos por que concatenas $IDM con $i, ni menos por que lo comparas con ""...

Comment: Varias cosas, talvez seria mejor almacenar los valores en un array y no en once variables.  Por otro lado no siempre es mejor utilizar un bucle.  Si el numero de llantas no va a aumentar considerablemente en el futuro, simplemente puedes chequear las variables una por una

Comment: Hola Excoripion, soy nuevo en la programacion. Mis codigos son largos como pueden notar. No puedo poner el codigo completo porque siempre me sale un error diciendo que hay mas codigo que explicacion, inclusive un dia intente que alguien me ayudara para saber como poner mi codigo, pero no tuve respuesta. Gracias por sus sugerencias.

Comment: Gracias alanfcm, voy a tener en cuenta sus observaciones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logramos que el código funcionara así:

```
$iM=0;
                            for ($i=1; $i<=11; $i=$i+1) { 
                                $IDM='IDM'.$i;
                                while ($$IDM!="") {
                                    $iM=$iM+1;
                                    break;
                                }
                                }
```

Como pueden notar, faltaba incluir esta linea
$IDM='IDM'.$i;